# Insert most recent cell on top of UITableView with pre-loader - SWIFT 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to add a newly created UITableViewCell (*A Firebase entry*) on top of the other cells - *which may or may not have been loaded before*.

This new post contains a variety of images and some text that is being fetched from Firebase.

I want it to have a pre-loader and a semi-transparent low resolution preview(optional), pushing down all the previous entries - similar to what Facebook, Instagram and others do when a user adds a new photo or post.

There are essentially 2 View Controllers:

**VC1:** Where the user creates the new post and adds a few photos etc. and the user will Segue 'from'

**VC2:** The list of entries (cells), the table view and data is retrieved.

I'm not quite sure where to start since VC2 just loads all the cells asynchronously, but the data is still being posted to firebase so it is likely to add the new post to the end...

At the moment it all loads - but I have no control over how to load the newly created post first.

*EDITED the observer code:*

```
func retrievePosts () {

        let postDB = Database.database().reference().child("Posts")

        postDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

            let snapshotValue =  snapshot.value as! Dictionary <String,AnyObject>

            let postID = snapshotValue ["EventID"]!
            let postBody = snapshotValue ["EventDescription"]!
            let postImageURL = snapshotValue ["EventTitleImage"]

            let post = Post()

            post.postID = postID as! String
            post.postBody =  postBody as! String
            post.postImageURL = postImageURL as! String

            postTableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
```

And the Create Post method looks like this:

```
func savePost() {

    let postEventDB = Database.database().reference().child("Posts")

    let postDictionary = [
        "PostID" : self.postID,
        "PostImage": postImageURL,
        "PostDescription": self.postDescription.text!,
        ] as [String : Any]

    postEventDB.child(self.eventID).setValue(postDictionary)  {
        (error, reference) in

        if error != nil {
            print (error!)
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I have no control over how to load the newly created post first` what that means? firebase is not returning it in correct order?

Comment: @Lu_ Sometimes it loads it first, sometimes it loads it last. I used an observer - so only when the data is live on FB does it load, I want some sort of placeholder on top while it saves that data to FB.

Comment: so you are building cells straight form firebase response? not even saving it to any array before that?

Comment: No it is based on "real-time" so it uses an observer.

Comment: I still can't see any code so I don't have any idea how it looks like

Comment: @Brewski providing code snippet / example helps understand the problem better.

Comment: Gotcha, added some code @Lu_

Comment: Still I don't see why are you creating `post` if you are not using it? and can you post code with creating cell?